# How to rename a type class operator in a subclass in Isabelle/HOL?

Tags: isabelle, type-class

I am trying to define a hierarchy of type classes with binary operations, in which the base class defines a binary operation `binop` and then each class `mult` and `add` redefines the binop to be a different name (`add` and `mult`, resp.). I saw the basic syntax in the Isabelle 2021 tutorial:

```
class binop = 
  fixes binop::"'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a" (infixl "∘" 75)

class mult = binop +
  fixes mult::"'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a" (infixl "⊗" 80)

class add = binop +
  fixes add::"'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a" (infixl "⊕" 70)
```

But the above approach defines a new operator in each subclass instead of specializing the existing `binop`. I have also tried instantiation unsuccessfully, but it seems conceptually wrong to begin with.

My question is:

*How can I reuse/redefine the class operation of the common base class?*

(My goal is to (learn to) define two different semigroups on `add` and `mult`, e.g. for some numeric types)

(I originally posted this question in SO, but didn't get much response. So I am deleting the question there and posting it here for more attention.)

Comment: `My goal is to (learn to) define two different semigroups on add and mult, e.g. for some numeric types`. A canonical methodology for this can be found in the theory Groups.thy in the main library of Isabelle/HOL. There you will find the definitions of the type classes `semigroup_add` and `semigroup_mult` that, I believe, serve the purpose that you intend. I am not certain if I understand the nature of the problem in your question, however.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you checked the general tutorial, but the one you need to look at is on [locales and locale interpretation](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2021-1/doc/locales.pdf), or the more specialized [Haskell-style type classes with Isabelle/Isar](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2021-1/doc/classes.pdf).

I'm more familiar with the first one. Actually, Isabelle classes are a particular case of the more general concept of *locale*. In Section 6 (“Locale Expressions”) of the first tutorial it is suggested that you use the base locale to define the new one, changing the symbol on the spot.

```
theory Scratch
  imports Main
begin

class binop = 
  fixes binop::"'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a" (infixl "∘" 75)

locale add = binop add for add (infixl "⊕" 70)

locale mult = binop mult for mult (infixl "⊗" 80)

locale ldistrib = add + mult +
  assumes
    left_distrib: "x ⊗ (y ⊕ z) = x ⊗ y ⊕  x ⊗ z"

end
```

The `for` clauses declare the new function names and establish the notation.

Comment: Surely, there must be a way to do this jsut using the `class` infrastructure but this was the first thing I got to compile.